# How do you write a code in Python that converts time between 4 zones with only for loops, if statements and strings

Tags: python, time, zone

How do you convert time in Python with only a limited number of tools? I know there is a method that does it but we have not covered it yet in the book. I know there is a similar question on this website, however the solution involves def which comes close to the end of the book that I'm using. I think the key is in using the strings because this exercise comes in the Strings chapter. It reads as follows (Source:A Practical Introduction to Python Programming by Brian Heinold):

> Write a program that converts a time from one time zone to another.
> The user enters the time in the usual American way, such as 3:48pm or
> 11:26am. The first time zone the user enters is that of the original
> time and the second is the desired time zone. The possible time zones
> are Eastern, Central, Mountain, or Pacific.
> Time: 11:48pm
> Starting zone: Pacific
> Ending zone: Eastern
> 2:48am

Here is my attempt that does not work:

```
#TIME ZONES:
#Pacific = 0
#Mountain = Pacific + 1
#Central = Mountain + 1
#Eastern = Central + 1

time = input("Time: ")
start = input("Starting zone: ")
end = input("Ending zone: ")

#An attempt to link the time zones to the variable i using numbers 0 to 3.

if start == "Pacific":
    s = 0
if start == "Mountain":
    s = 1
if start == "Central":
    s = 2
if start == "Eastern":
    s = 3

if end == "Pacific":
    e = 0
if end == "Mountain":
    e = 1
if end == "Central":
    e = 2
if end == "Eastern":
    e = 3

# This is where the problem shows up.
# I've tried multiple ways to convert the hours part
# from a string into an integer but none of them worked.
# Yes, I know that after I'm done I'll have to deal with
# the limited number of hours and switching from am to pm
# and vice versa but I need to solve this part first.

for i in range(4):
    hours = int(time[:1])
    time_h = hours + i
    time = str(time_h)+time[1:]
    if i == s:
        #print ("Starting zone: ", time)
    if i == e:
        print (time)
```

Comment: You are hard-coding the length of the hours but it can be one or two digits. Split on `":"` and convert the parts after splitting off and parsing the am/pm suffix. Also, your offsets seem to be reversed (Pacific is Eastern + 3, not vice versa).

Comment: @tripleee, thank you for your comment. I'll try to figure out how to use that to revise my code.